# ¿Como esperar en un servicio que un procedimiento en termine?

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

les cuento que estoy trabajando en una Aplicación en Angular, .Net Core y SQL Server, tengo un procedimiento que hace un gran calculo por lo tanto se puede demorar hasta 30 minutos, lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario pueda ejecutar esa acción de manera asíncrona en el front, es decir que el usuario de desentienda y pueda seguir haciendo otras cosas, entonces el servicio invoque el SP y espere a que este se ejecute completamente, estuve tratando de ejecutar  el SP en el servicio pero me genera un error de timeout, vi que se puede aumentar este tiempo pero quisiera otra solución u otra forma de hacer esto. Básicamente quiero que la ejecución en base de datos se mantenga viva.

Comment: Cómo tienes configurado los pool de la conexión en .net ?

Comment: No lo he hecho ninguna configuración porque básicamente esto haciendo una prueba de concepto.

Comment: Estas duplicando tu pregunta con pequeños matices.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Que técnicas asincrónicas puedo usar para ejecutar un calculo en base de datos que puede demorar hasta 30 minutos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363587/que-t%c3%a9cnicas-asincr%c3%b3nicas-puedo-usar-para-ejecutar-un-calculo-en-base-de-datos)

Comment: El usuario de la aplicación Web es independiente de la sesión con el usuario de BD. La ejecución del SP normalmente va a correr hasta que termine y ya está en la lógica de tu aplicación el tener un hilo con ese proceso en segundo plano, mientras el proceso principal en tu aplicación continúa con la ejecución sin esperar el resultado y no bloquea la navegación.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer sobre los procesos sincronos y asincronos en tu caso necesitas uno sincrono.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar HangFire para encolar el proceso y que se ejecute en segundo plano